# C++: Changing global variable in multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I don't really know much about threads in c++. Here is a simple code:

```
int a = 0;

int main()
{
    std::thread t1([=]() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            a += 1;
            std::cout << "A in another thread: " << a << std::endl;
        }
        });
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        a += 1;
        std::cout << "A in main: " << a << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I run this code it gives me a `Debug Error: abort() has been called`.
How can I change a global variable's value on multiple threads?

Comment: The problem isn't the race condition (which is still a problem). The problem is you're not joining, nor detaching, your created thread. The program should have `t1.join();` after your main-loop, but before `main` exits.

Comment: Notice - the lambda captures `a` by value (a copy). There is no race, but probably the program won't do what expected.

Comment: you can read about `std::thread` eg here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread. Trial and error is not a good approach with multithreading, because there are just too many things one can do wrong and not always it is obvious when code is broken

Answer (score 1):

because you didn't joined thread after your programme finished. OS will send SIGABRT to detached thread to avoid this problem you should join the thread.

you should put below line at end of main:

```
t1.join()
```

Note: beware about possible race condition on variable a.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues:
First of all when you start another thread you have to `join` it or `detach` before the program terminates.
Second thing is that you can read the same variable from many threads, but writing to it creates race condition.